# npm npm_folder gruntfile relative root path specification

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm

I want ot ser my node operations in lib folder and my project structure is like this,

- src
- lib

  - node_modules
  - package.json
  - Gruntfile.js
- doc

So I am using **concat** task,

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

    grunt.initConfig({
      concat: {
        dist: {
          src: ['../src/js/controller.js', '../src/js/service.js'],
          dest: '../dist/js/built.js',
        },
      },
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
}
```

This wokrs and creates **built.js** file in **dist** folder. But I should use "../" all paths and I will have so many configuration. Can I set it as a root path only one time in **Gruntfile.js**. Is there any settings like `{root:"../"}` this?